# What's the angle between B and C?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the vectors $$A , B, C \in  \mathbb R^3$$

with:

$$\left||A\right|| = \left||C\right|| =5$$
$$\left||B\right||= 1$$
$$\left||A - B + C\right|| = \left||A + B + C\right||$$

And the angle that A and B form is $$\frac{\pi}{8}$$
Then, what's the angle between B and C?

Answer (score 1):

It is true in general that ...
$$ ||x+y||=||x-y|| \iff x\cdot y=0$$

so

$$||A+C+B||=||A+C-B|| \iff B\cdot (A+C)=0 \implies B.A = - B.C $$

let $\theta$ represent the angle between B and C then ...

$$\cos \theta =-\cos \frac{\pi}{8} $$